# R Convert <key, val> pair into data.frame

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

In R, I have two vectors of  pairs like this:

```
x <- c("A=5", "B=1",        "D=1", "E=1", "F=2", "G=1")
y <- c("A=2", "B=1", "C=3", "D=1",                     "H=4")
```

I would like to convert this into a data.frame like this:

```
  A B C D E F G H
x 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0
y 2 1 3 1 0 0 0 4
```

All keys contained in either x or y should make up the columns, keys that do not appear in x or y should be added with value zero.

Comment: Do you have a character vector, or a named numeric vector (`x <- c(A=5,B=1,D=1)`)?

Comment: ...Two test cases spring to mind: `y <- x` and `y <- character(0)`. My solution handles both ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Not the prettiest solution but easy to follow:**

*1) Parse your string to a data frame:*

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(strsplit(x, '='), rbind), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Result:

```
> as.data.frame(sapply(strsplit(x, '='), rbind), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  A  B  D  E  F  G
2  5  1  1  1  2  1
```

*2) Give header:*

```
names(df1) <- df1[1,]
df1 <- df1[-1,]
```

Result:

```
> df1
  A B D E F G
2 5 1 1 1 2 1
```

*3) Do the same for your other string:*

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(strsplit(y, '='), rbind), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df2) <- df2[1,]
df2 <- df2[-1,]
```

*4) Merge those:*

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE, sort=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
> df
  A B D    E    F    G    C    H
1 2 1 1 <NA> <NA> <NA>    3    4
2 5 1 1    1    2    1 <NA> <NA>
```

---

**Update**: the above all-in-one with some makeup based on comments:

```
> df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(strsplit(x, '='), rbind), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> names(df1) <- df1[1,]
> df1 <- df1[-1,]
> 
> df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(strsplit(y, '='), rbind), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> names(df2) <- df2[1,]
> df2 <- df2[-1,]
> 
> library(reshape)
> df <- rbind.fill(df1,df2)
> df[is.na(df)] <- 0
> df <- df[, order(names(df))]
> df
  A B C D E F G H
1 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0
2 2 1 3 1 0 0 0 4
```

Comment: And to replace the NAs with 0s: `df[is.na(df)] <- 0`

Comment: And I also forgot about the fact that the column order is not perfect so after filling up the data frame with zeros (see @jthetzel's comment), you can do a reorder like: `df[,order(names(df))]`

Comment: Thanks @djhurio: good remark what I did not concerned. I have updated my answer to eliminate that problem. May the negative vote fade out then? :)

Comment: Thanks for the sporting gesture! :)

Comment: I ended up adopting this approach because it can nicely be integrated into a loop to merge not just x and y but more vectors.
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here's an environment based approach. Make separate environments into which the name=val pairs are evaluated. Then merge them:

```
xe <- new.env()
ye <- new.env()
with(xe, eval(parse(text=x)))
with(ye, eval(parse(text=y)))
# > ls(env=ye)
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "H"
# edit as. list makes even more compact!
 df1 <- merge(as.list(xe), as.list(ye), all=TRUE, sort=FALSE)  
 # sort keeps row order with x on top!
  A B D  E  F  G  C  H
1 5 1 1  1  2  1 NA NA
2 2 1 1 NA NA NA  3  4

 df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
 df1
  A B D E F G C H
1 2 1 1 0 0 0 3 4
2 5 1 1 1 2 1 0 0
```

The problem with the two arguments being equal leading to loss of one line is solved with the reshape::rbind.fill method.

```
df1 <- rbind.fill(as.data.frame(as.list(xe)), as.data.frame(as.list(ye)) )
```

Comment: Nice approach, thanks for sharing (+1)! Anyway, as @djhurio suggested below: `merge` might not be the best solution. See my updated answer.

Comment: Cool! That's thinking outside the box! ...but you could simplify a bit with `eval(parse(text=x), xe)` instead of calling `with`.

Comment: @Tommy I think maybe you meant "That's thinking outside the global environment!" ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here's another variant:

```
x <- c("A=5", "B=1","D=1", "E=1", "F=2", "G=1")
y <- c("A=2", "B=1", "C=3", "D=1","H=4")

# Extract names & values
m <- do.call('cbind', strsplit(x, '='))
xn <- m[1,]
xv <- as.numeric(m[2,])
m <- do.call('cbind', strsplit(y, '='))
yn <- m[1,]
yv <- as.numeric(m[2,])

# Merge names    
an <- sort(union(xn,yn))

# Assemble result
r <- matrix(0, 2, length(an), dimnames=list(NULL, an))
r[1,xn] <- xv
r[2,yn] <- yv

# Inspect result:
r
#     A B C D E F G H
#[1,] 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0
#[2,] 2 1 3 1 0 0 0 4

# ...if you want a data.frame instead of a matrix:
as.data.frame(r)
#  A B C D E F G H
#1 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0
#2 2 1 3 1 0 0 0 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my solution.

```
x <- c("A=11", "B=1", "D=1", "E=1", "F=2", "GZ=1")
y <- c("A=2", "B=1", "C=3", "D=1", "H=4")

pos.x <- as.numeric(regexpr("=", x))
pos.y <- as.numeric(regexpr("=", y))

x.1 <- data.frame(key=substring(x,1,pos.x-1),
                  x=as.numeric(substring(x,pos.x+1)),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)

y.1 <- data.frame(key=substring(y,1,pos.y-1),
                  y=as.numeric(substring(y,pos.y+1)),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)

d <- merge(x.1, y.1, all=T)

d[is.na(d)] <- 0

row.names(d) <- d$key
d$key <- NULL

d <- as.data.frame(t(d))

d
class(d)
```

Comment: Did you think about the issue if `A` might be bigger than `9`? That would result in *your* code's failure :)

Comment: Err, I was not competing, just made a justifiable "counterattack" :) Anyway, +1 for updated, universally working code!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `eval(parse)`

```
vec2list <- function(x){
  x_con <- paste(x, collapse = ",")
  eval(parse(text = paste('list(', x_con, ')')))
}

plyr::ldply(llply(list(x, y), vec2list), data.frame)

  A B D  E  F  G  C  H
1 5 1 1  1  2  1 NA NA
2 2 1 1 NA NA NA  3  4
```