# Associative array from string

Tags: r, text

I would like to create an associative array in R from a string like `"key1=values1;key2=value2"`. I know this can be done by double splitting  and building the array manually but i was wondering if there's already something i can work with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R Convert <key, val> pair into data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127869/r-convert-key-val-pair-into-data-frame)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an environment as the "associative array" provides a straightforward solution.

```
string <- "key1=99; key2=6"

# Create an environment which will be your array
env <- new.env()

# Assign values to keys in the environment, using eval(parse())
eval(parse(text=string), envir=env)

# Check that it works:
ls(env)
# [1] "key1" "key2"
env$key1
# [1] 99

as.list(env)
# $key1
# [1] 99

# $key2
# [1] 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using `eval(parse)`

```
string <- c("key1 = 10, key2 = 20")
eval(parse(text = paste('list(', string, ")")))
$key1
[1] 10

$key2
[1] 20
```